# Magento 2.3 - Changing Category Name in specific Store View

Tags: magento2.3

I am using Magento 2.3.0.

I get my products from CSV feed - they are generated and within their generation, also Product Categories are generated.

All of the Product Categories are created under Default Category - all of Store Views use default Category Name values at the moment. It is important that one product has only one Category, which is transated through Store View.

How can I change Product Category Name within specific Store View programmatically?

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overthinked it and the answer was easier than expected:

During parsing, I created an array with Store View name as a key and translations as values.

Then I looped through them, editing data. $result->id is the main category ID which I just created previously

```
    foreach($translations as $key => $value){
        try {
            $storeViewId = $this->storeManager->getStore($key)->getId();

            $viewCategory = $this->categoryFactory->create()->setStoreId($storeViewId)->load($result->getId());
            $viewCategory->setName($value);
            $viewCategory->save();

            $this->_logger->notice('Created View Category for. '.$result->getName().' Lang: '. $key. ' Value:' .$value);

        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            $this->_logger->notice('FAILED CREATION OF CATEGORY translation for: '. $result->getName().' Lang: '. $key. ' Value:' .$value);
        }
    }
```

**If anyone has a better solution, please let me know**